# Google OAuth sign-in no longer works

Tags: google-signin

My production webapps have been working great with Google, users sign in with a "Sign-in With Google" button.  Yesterday it just stopped working for some strange reason.  Users can enter their credentials for Google OAuth, but there's no redirect back to my site, and it times out after 1 minute with a Cancellation Exception.  My development machines work fine, so it makes me think my IP/domains are somehow blacklisted by Google.  How can I troubleshoot this?  Things look fine in the Google Dev Console, and didn't change.

Here's the exception I get:

```
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
EventId: 1
RequestId: 800003a6-0000-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /signin-google
SpanId: |1ef968c6-4314b979fec6a574.
TraceId: 1ef968c6-4314b979fec6a574
ParentId: 

An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

Exception: 
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthHandler`1.ExchangeCodeAsync(OAuthCodeExchangeContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthHandler`1.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

Comment: Hey, you'd probably want to provide more context here to get better help. What logs do you see after you click "Sign-in With Google", copy the URL it takes you too and investigate for any discrepancies like incorrect redirect URL. Check your server/app logs you might find some help there too.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that for Google's OAuth you can only sign in 100 times before they need to have all your scopes approved on the Google Dev Console.  This applies to your real domain, not developing on localhost, which always works.

There was no error message when I hit 100, just a timeout after 1 minute.  It all worked fine again once Google approved my site.